# NHibernate - Select Id from reference column without join

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, reference, fluent-nhibernate

i have two simple objects A and B. Object A has a reference to object B.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual Guid AId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual B BObject { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public virtual Guid BId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I mapped these two objects with Fluent-NHibernate:

```
public class AMap : ClassMap<A>
{
    public AMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.AId);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References<B>(x => x.BObject);
    }
}

public class BMap : ClassMap<B>
{
    public BMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.BId);
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

After creating the database I get two tables. The table of A has an additional column 'BObject_id'.

I have a special case where I only need to select the id of the referenced object B.
I use LINQ to select this.

```
var test = session.Query<A>().Select(x => x.BObject.BId);
```

This produces the sql query (I'm using MSSQL2012):

```
select b1_.BId as col_0_0_ from iadb.[A] a0_ left outer join iadb.[B] b1_ on a0_.BObject_id=b1_.BId
```

Hibernate joins the two tables first and then selects the key column of B

My question is:

Is it possible to select only the value of the column 'BOject_id' from table A?

I want to avoid the join in this special case and use the benefit of references in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend your C# class `A` with a *readonly* `BId` property:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual Guid AId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual B BObject { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid BId { get; set; } // virtual "navigational" property
}
```

Map it as *readonly*. It is important, because it will target the same column as a reference BObject.

```
public AMap()
{
  Id(x => x.AId);
  Map(x => x.Name);
  References<B>(x => x.BObject)
    .Column("BOject_id");
  Map(x => x.BId)
    .Column("BOject_id") // the same column names
    .ReadOnly();
}
```

And now you can get it without a join:

```
var test = session.Query<A>().Select(x => x.BId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
var test = session.Query<A>().Select(x => x.BObject).Select(x => x.BId);
```

NHibernate should create proxy for B without join in this case, and accessing identifier only of created proxy should not trigger DB access.